# Jmeter - Simular milhares de usuários simultâneos

Tags: rest

Desenvolvi uma API Rest, e estou realizando alguns testes na etapa de homologação. Esta API tem a função de integrar determinadas informações do banco de dados de filiais com o banco de dados da matriz.

Gostaria de saber se com o JMeter é possível realizar testes simulando milhares de conexões de usuários?

Dessa forma, ter uma ideia de qual é a carga de conexões simultâneas, o tempo para cada processo, o desempenho e etc. Seria algo mais ou menos assim:

- Testes simulando processos em lotes, como por exemplo 500 usuários, enviando 1000 registros cada um (POST) p/ salvar no banco de dados da API.

Com o Jmeter  é possível realizar esses testes? Ou tem alguma outra tecnologia que me ajudaria melhor nessa situação?